# Default reply in Mail.app depending on sender

Tags: apple-mail

How can I do int in Mail.app (OSX) so that depending on the email sender (whether it is from gmail.com or yahoo.com, etc), I reply from my gmail or yahoo (or other) account?

Answer (score 0):

*This response is based off Mail.app 7.3 from OS X Mavericks 10.9.3*

By default, Mail.app will reply from the account to which the email was sent. So if you have two accounts:

- `john@gmail.com`
- `superco@superco.com`

Hitting reply on an email to `john@gmail.com` will open up a new reply email, with `john@gmail.com` as the sender. Likewise, replying to an email sent to `superco@yahoo.com` will default to that address as the sender.

If you have set up aliases on the accounts, e.g:

- `john@gmail.com`
- `superco@superco.com`, `support@superco.com`

Then an email to `support@superco.com` will default to replying from `support@superco.com`.

Mail.app has a single setting to modify this behaviour, in the **Composing** tab in its preferences, you can change the setting:

```
Send new messages from: Account of selected mailbox
                        John <john@gmail.com>
                        SuperCo <superco@superco.com>
                        SuperCo Support <support@superco.com>
```

Which really just forces a single sender instead of the above, default behaviour.

Unfortunately at this point there's no way to choose a particular account or alias based on the recipient or sender of the email you're replying to. You could try [giving Apple some feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html) though.